# OPENCV mean value of image using only values under a threshold

Tags: python-2.7, opencv, mean, mask

I have the intensity values from a row of a gray scale image (0-255) as in the image. I want to apply pixel centering so I subtract the mean value from all the intensity values. But I don't want to include values higher than 200. What is the best way to do it without iterating through the image? I tried the `cv2.mean(input, mask)` but I couldn't set the mask properly. I tried also the `mean(x for x in mid_line if x < 200)` from the `statistics` library but the resulted mean is incorrect.

[image]

Comment: Python 2.7 has been obsolete for over a year and Python 3 has been out nearly 13 years... maybe consider developing new code in Python 3.

Comment: I chose python 2.7 because of compatibility with a larger project, which was on 2.7 already. But thanks for the note!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a mask using `cv2.threshold`. You need to set all values above 200 to 0 and the ones below it to 255, hence, the flag needs to be set to `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`.

```
import cv2

# assuming row has your values
ret, thresh = cv2.threshold(row, 200, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
result = cv2.mean(row, thresh)
```

This will only calculate the mean of pixels less equal to 200.

Comment: That solved my problem. I calculated the mean value with and without the mask and the results were 39 and 51 respectively, which makes sense. Thanks!